# Из excel в текст

Tags: excel

Задача сохранить обычную таблицу excel в виде текстового файла. Загвоздка в том что нужно чтобы в каждой строке было прописано название столбца.
Например таблица вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в Excel.

Из этого нужно получить текстовый файл вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Экспортировать в csv-файл, а потом find-and-replace в каком-нибудь Notepad++ добавить названия столбцов. Такой ответ подоходит?

Comment: JSON формируете, что ли?

Comment: @mrEvgenX, а что заменять то будем?)

Comment: Регулярку можно попробовать, допустим такую с ходу `^(\d+),([\w\d]+),(\d+)$`, а заменить на `Id=\1,name=\2,amount=\3` (https://regex101.com/r/X1QoUa/2). Но способ в ответе явно проще.

Comment: @mrEvgenX, как вариант, но да, соглашусь в ответе проще, а главное силами самого excel. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте в еще один столбец, и впишите туда формулу с конкатенацией ячеек

```
=A$1&" = "&A2&", "&B$1&" = "&B2 // и т.д
```

скопируйте полученный столбец в файл.

или можно прямо прописать названия столбцов в формулу

```
="id = "&A2&", name = "&B2
```

Comment: На большом кол-ве данных не сработает. 1) Буфер обрезает поля до 255 символов 2) Ограничение на кол-во копируемых строк.

Comment: @iluxa1810 эксель 95 что ли? я подобным образом периодически генерирую скрипты для вставки данных в БД, ни разу не сталкивался с подобным.

Comment: Отличный способ, спасибо!

Comment: @teran Не. В 2010 ловил такие ошибки и проблемы.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вы утверждаете, что если в эксель вставить абзац текста (больше 255), то его не получится скопировать? мб проверить для начала стоит?

Comment: @teran ну хрен его знает. Между Access и Excel точно у меня траблы были.